# Kafka : Is sending some payload data (identifier) in headers considered a good practive?

Tags: event-programming, messaging, event, apache-kafka, event-handling

I am wondering about some architectonical decisions in our system.

There are situations where we are sending import business events through kafka which should be performed in every case.

All the cases are working just fine except one - deserialization issues.

We want to be informed when particular event has not been properly handled.

My idea is to send some payload data in headers, in most cases just one field - identifier. If data could not been deserialized for some reasons, then handlers would just take that identifier and inform about that in correct places, not just seeing that info in logs and not knowing that something like that happened a few hours later.

So I am wondering if such an approach is good enough/if sending such a data in headers is a good approach - maybe there are better solutions.

Thanks for all the answers

Comment: Why do you call it payload data? If I understand correctly there is no payload data because deserialization failed. You then basically want to inform subscribers their message got lost and why, because, in case of deserialization problems, you can. That sounds like meta data to me and if that helps signaling a problem early it would be a good thing.

Comment: By "payload" I meant that some headers are the same as data in payload, so I thought it would be a redundacy for every event, but yeah, this is a metadata and purpose of that data is different from "Payload", so it might be not considered as redundancy

Comment: If the data is 'metadata' then that suggests its only purpose is for communication so it probably shouldn't be in the Payload at all.